# Find the lengths of sides of a triangle of greatest area given its perimeter and one of the interior angles .

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

The perimeter of a triangle is known to be $24$-units with one of the interior angles equal to $60^\circ $. Find the lengths of the three sides of the triangle if it has the maximum possible area.

Can the problem be done by method of one-variable calculus(i.e without using partial differentiation) or by some algebraic inequalities.

Comment: Say $\angle C = 60^\circ$ and WLOG, $a$ is the longest side then $b \leq c \leq a$. In other words if $a$ is the longest side, $b$ is the smallest and as we increase $a$, $b$ decreases given $A + B = 120^\circ$ and perimeter is fixed. The area of the triangle is $\frac{a b \sin 60^\circ}{2}$. I think using these and triangular inequality, you should be able to show that $a = b = c$ gives the maximum area.

Comment: Let the two sides including the given angle be $x$ and $y$. So, the third side will be $24-x-y$. Use cosine rule on the given angle to determine the third side opposite to the given angle in terms of $x$ and $y$ and obtain the value of either of the two. This reduces the problem to a single variable calculus problem.

Comment: @RiverX15. I followed your method and obtained a neat solution. You should have written this as a full blown answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof uses a bit of topology and elementary knowledge of ellipses.

If the perimeter is $p=a+b+c$, then the set of potential lengths of the sides (for a potentially degenerate triangle!) is given by $a+b+c=p, a\ge 0, b\ge 0, c\ge 0, a\le b+c, b\le a+c, c\le a+b$, which is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^3$.

This means that the area (e.g. given by Heron's formula), as a continuous function of the lengths $a, b, c$, must achieve a maximum in the above set.

However, the maximum is obviously *not* achieved the triangle is degenerate. It is not achieved either if the triangle is not degenerate but two sides are nonequal. Namely, it is easy to see that, with a given $a$, which then fixes $b+c=p-a$, the maximum is achieved when $b=c$. (The locus of the corner opposite to side $a$ is an arc of an ellipse, and the point the most distant from side $a$ is on the bisector of this side.)

Thus, the maximum is achieved when all three sides are equal. This means $a=b=c=p/3$. This triangle will have an angle of $60^\circ$ and will therefore be the maximum among *those* triangles (having an angle of $60^\circ$).

Conclusion: the triangle is equilateral with sides $a=b=c=8$.